How to resize floating window (popup view) of an Android app to specific size by ADB command
I'm building an auto app for multiwindow testing for android app. The app will open any android app in popup view(floating view) then change the size of window randomly (600x800....)
im trying to use adb to send command to device. However, i can not find an exact command.
I tried adb shell wm size 800x600. But it changed the whole resolution of device.
